# Selecting only a sequence

Tags: db2-400

I would like to select in my table only a part after i read 00006 and stop selecting  when i read the next pattern 00XXX .(here it's 00040 but it's could be an another number )

```
00006 
123456
456789
123789
00040
125478
547896
454623
519846
00001
....
```

Here , for example i would like to get only these values with a select :

123456
456789
123789

How is the way to obtain that ? I dont find any clue.

Thanks for your help.

ps: i have no rights for transform the table where i select

**With the solution of Charles :**

```
with marker as (
   select rownumber() over() as rowno
          , rrn(t) as recno, cast(substr(YYYYYY, 1, 5)as integer) as markvalue
   from fap1t010.£$ZZZZZZ t
   where substr(YYYYYY, 1, 5) like ('00___')
 ), dataa as (
   select rrn(t) as recno, cast(substr(YYYYYY, 1, 6)as integer) as datavalue
   from fap1t010.£$ZZZZZZ t
   where substr(YYYYYY, 1, 5) NOT like ('00006')
   and substr(YYYYYY, 13, 1) ='C'
), ranges as(
   select a.markvalue
         , a.recno as startrec
         , b.recno as endrec
   from marker A join marker B
     on b.rowno = a.rowno +1
)
 select distinct d.datavalue  
 from ranges R join dataa D
      on d.recno between r.startrec and r.endrec
 where r.markvalue = 00006
```

Comment: There aren't any other columns in the table?

Comment: No, i have just one colum in the table

Comment: How is it accessed now?  I can't even imagine RPGLE reading the table as described...

Comment: In fact , it's just a save table from a flux send. This flux is reading by a soft. I need actually to read this table for understand a problem.

Comment: Looks like the column is character?

Comment: Yeah it is, but i just use some  cast integer on your solution and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow...that's an ugly request.

But it can be done:

```
with marker as (
   select rownumber() over() as rowno
          , rrn(t) as recno, myfld as markvalue
   from dtcwilt.temp t
   where myfld like ('00___ ')
 ), data as (
   select rrn(t) as recno, myfld as datavalue
   from dtcwilt.temp t
   where myfld NOT like ('00___ ')
), ranges as(
   select a.markvalue
         , a.recno as startrec
         , b.recno as endrec
   from marker A join marker B
     on b.rowno = a.rowno +1
)
 select d.datavalue  
 from ranges R join data D
      on d.recno between r.startrec and r.endrec
 where r.markvalue = '00006';
```

If you have a large data set, performance isn't going to be all that great;  there's probably room for improvement.  But the above is at least easy to understand.

If you happen to be on the latest version 7.3 of IBM i, you could probably simplify the statement by making use of the new `LEAD()` and/or `LAG()` functions.  But I don't have 7.3 to test on.

Comment: I will try  your solution today, i will keep you updated